# jQuery loading graphic shows broken image

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, loading, graphic

I have a loading graphic setup for a links to other pages on my site. 60% of the time graphic shows but the other times the popup loading message appears and the image shows broken. Below is the script that is used on click of the specific a links.

jQuery:

```
overlayElem.append("<div class='loadingOverlay overElem'><img src='/Images/Graphics/loadera64.gif' style='width:64px; margin:"+spinnerPos+" auto; display:block;' /></div>");
```

Are there any common reasons the image would be shown as broken e.g. not having time to put it in before the page leave is initiated to to go to the next webpage etc.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that "spinnerPos" has a px on the end.
2. Check spelling/case - Note that Linux treats "/Images" differently to "/images"

Comment: Hi this is all fine, like I said works 60% of the time, just on odd occasions maybe 4 in 10 it shows the text and the image as a broken image